# Get func placeholder values from a snippet to appear after hitting tab at top level code level

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete, code-snippets

New to swift and xcode, version 11.3.1.

If I hit `func<tab>` in a class, the placeholder values pop in nicely and I can tab through them to complete them.

However, when I have a simple playground file open and hit `func<tab>` I don't see any placeholder values. Just the keyword `func` appears.

How do I turn on these placeholder values for top-level functions?

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about are "code snippets". You can insert them not only by typing the "magic word", but also by clicking on the plus sign on the top right, then choosing from the list:

[image]

If you search for "Function", you can find the one you're looking for.

But who wants to *click a button* when writing code, right? It seems like some of the snippets somehow can't be used in playgrounds, while others *can*. This seems like an Xcode bug. For me, things like `var`, `varget`, `vargetset` all worked.

As an workaround, you can create your own code snippet for a function. First, paste this code into Xcode:

```
func <#name#>(<#parameters#>) -> <#return type#> {
    <#function body#>
}
```

Select all of it, then go to Editor -> Create Code Snippet. Give it a name, and most importantly, a "Completion".

[image]

Apparently, you can still put `func` as the "Completion" and it will work.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with creating my own snippets. But specifically, when I'm in a "playground" file, no snippet pops  up with `func`.

I ended up hacking the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESourceEditor.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets file and changing the  `<key>IDECodeSnippetCompletionScopes</key>` to "All"

Comment: Hmm, I really feel like this is a bug in Xcode. If you change the scope of your own code snippet to "Class Implementation and Top Level" (same as the built-in "Function Statement" snippet), it will still work...

Comment: @StevieD On second thought, maybe the built in snippets are behaving correctly, and it's the user-created snippets that are not. If I create a snippet with the scope "Comment or String", I can somehow still use it at top level in a playground. My theory is that the top level in a playground isn't really top level. It's considered a "Function or Method" by Xcode, which is why you can't use code snippets that have a scope of "Class Implementation or Top Level".

Comment: What I don't get is that I hacked the xml file to change the scope to "All". If the playground file isn't `top level`, what exactly is it? I would assume any function in the main body of a file would be considered "top level". I clearly must not understand how playgrounds are structured.

Comment: @StevieD According to my testing, it seems to be "Function or Method", as I said in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a better answer but here is what worked to get the func snippet to show up while editing a "playground" file:

1) Edit snippets file with: `sudo vim /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESourceEditor.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets`

2) Search for snippet and find the related scope key and modify the array of the scope key to `<string>All</string>`:

```
        <key>IDECodeSnippetCompletionScopes</key>
        <array>
            <string>All</string>
        </array>
```

Yes, I could create my own snippet which is the same as the built-in snippet but then I have two different snippets that do the same thing, which I found annoying.